# Cython read large binary file using class definition

Tags: class, cython, readfile, large-files

My code tries to read a binary file using a Structure class:

```
import os
import mmap
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint

class StructFile(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('Xmin', c_uint),('Ymax', c_uint)]

fd = os.open(filePath, os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY)
mmap_file = mmap.mmap(fd, length=ln, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, offset=0)
d_arrayFile = StructFile * numItems
data = d_arrayFile.from_buffer(mmap_file)
for i in data:
    print i.Xmin, i.Ymax
```

It works correctly, but I would like to speed it up using a cython class. The problem is when I use `cdef class StructFile(Structure):` the compilation says: "'Structure' is not a type name".

How could I do in order to cython recognise 'Structure' as a type name like 'int', 'object', etc.? Or any other solution to optimise the code (not using struct.unpack).

Thanks!

Comment: Which bit of your code do you expect Cython to speed up? The only bit it might be able to help with is the iteration over the array, and it isn't obvious how you'd do that.

Comment: I'd like to speed up class definition, using `cdef class name(args)` instead of `class name(args)`, but argument 'Structure' is not a type name and I can't use it in a cython class definition. Well, if you know how to speed up any other bit of code (like the iteration) it's also ok.

Comment: The class definition is run once and is really quick to run. I honestly don't see how a cdef class will help.

Comment: Actually, it is run many times. I just showed an easier example. But it's ok if you think that a `cdef class` won't help. I asked this question because I tried 2 codes (this one and another one using `struct.unpack`), being `struct.unpack` faster (I thought it was strange, because it should be slower). And it's why I thought it was due to `cdef class` or maybe to the loop. Thank you!

Comment: The one additional thing I might try is using `numpy.frombuffer` with `dtype=[('Xmin','u4'),('Ymin','u4')]`. However, I can't get mmap to work so I can't really test anything.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it comparing processing times